# is iOS/Metal possible to read pixel depth?

Tags: ios, swift, metal

I want to read depth on a certain point(x, y). In OpenGL, it's `glReadPixels`, but `OpenGL ES` does not support reading `depth`. So I wonder if `iOS/Metal` can do the trick.

There are few examples that I can find, I've checked other questions but few people answered and those answers are not complete.

A similar question is:
[iOS/Metal: how to read from the depth buffer at a point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28424883/ios-metal-how-to-read-from-the-depth-buffer-at-a-point)
but it's four years ago. and I don't understand the only answer. Forgive me that I am a very new metal user. I wonder if there is a better way now with newest swift and metal.

I have a `draw` function shown below,

```swift
func draw(in view: MTKView) {
        guard let drawable = view.currentDrawable,
            let pipelineState = pipelineState,
            let descriptor = view.currentRenderPassDescriptor else { return }

        let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()
        let commandEncoder = commandBuffer?.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: descriptor)
        commandEncoder?.setRenderPipelineState(pipelineState)

        plane2.draw(view, commandEncoder)
        plane.draw(view, commandEncoder)

        commandEncoder?.endEncoding()
        commandBuffer?.present(drawable)
        commandBuffer?.commit()

    }
```

my pipelineState is:

```swift
let library = device.makeDefaultLibrary()
        let vertexFunction = library?.makeFunction(name: "vertex_shader")
        let fragmentFunction = library?.makeFunction(name: "fragment_shader")

        let pipelineDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
        pipelineDescriptor.vertexFunction = vertexFunction
        pipelineDescriptor.fragmentFunction = fragmentFunction
        pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm

        do {
            pipelineState = try device.makeRenderPipelineState(descriptor: pipelineDescriptor)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
```

My app is very simple. just `lines`, `triangles` without textures, only primitive geometry. I expect to read the `depth` from a `Touched point` and unproject which to my camera view.

Comment: So you currently don't have a depth buffer? It seems that you're not configuring the depth attachment on your render pipeline descriptor, nor are you setting a depth-stencil state when drawing.

Comment: hi, @warrenm. Thank you for your answer. Since I'm very new to metal, can you please tell me how to properly set depth buffer in my case? or just tell how to read depth from depth buffer, Thank you very much, I really need this trick

Comment: I know ray tracing can pick objects. But in my case, I have only lines, points, which does not have volume, so I think ray tracing does not fit my application.